# Raspberry pi OS can't load lightdm

Tags: raspberry-pi, remote, lightdm

Running the Pi using physical monitor works fine. But without HDMI connection, The NoMachine couldn't find any display running. Trying start lightdm using `service lighdm start` via ssh didn't works, as well `systemctl` . I got the next error:

```
● lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-09-23 16:55:28 IDT; 8s ago
     Docs: man:lightdm(1)
  Process: 1702 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/sbin/lightdm" ] (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1704 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lightdm (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1704 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 23 16:55:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Sep 23 16:55:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Sep 23 16:55:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Light Display Manager.
Sep 23 16:55:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 23 16:55:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 23 16:55:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Light Display Manager.
Sep 23 16:55:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
```

Comment: Give `journalctl` log

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.